# Как по порядковым номерам обработать ключи firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-android

Есть база данных в firebase. В ней есть каталоги, в каталогах есть ключи с рандомным именем и токеном регистрации в значении. Каждый ключ присваивается клиенту, некий id, приложение запоминает его. Как обработать все токены одного каталога, не зная имени ключа?

Answer (score 1):

Получить ключ можно можно методом getKey(). Например.

```
DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
List<String> mKeys = new ArrayList<>();
databaseRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            mKeys.add(key);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            ----
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ----
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            ----
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            ----
        }
    });
```

Добавить все объекты можно так:

```
ArrayList<SomeObject> list;
String path = "table1/table2"; //путь к таблице
databaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            list = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();
            for (DataSnapshot objectRecord : dataSnapshot.child(path).getChildren()) {
                SomeObject someObject = objectRecord.getValue(SomeObject.class);
                list.add(someObject);
        }    

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Поля объекта SomeObject совпадают, соответственно, с полями, указанными в базе.

Answer (score 0):

Вот некий туторил [Fire base уроки](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-gZAYBMuBs&list=PLGCjwl1RrtcTXrWuRTa59RyRmQ4OedWrt)  по `FireBase` там есть почти все  и на все случаии.Хоть и на английском можеш перевести через переводчик в общим и целом суть думаю поймешь.Удачи!И чисто совет не пользуйся дб от Фаира если нет надобности в бд реалтайм.она много жрет и часто не оправдывает себя.Удачи

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку! Но риалтайм бд действительно нужна

Comment: Конечно я не спорю )я говорю о сути бд )если утебя не чат или не блог то я думаю лишнее использование бд)ну я так привык надеюсь видео вам поможет .там около 40 уроков и точно помню была тема ключей

Comment: А есть какой-то конкретный ответ или пример кода?